# Proving $\cos^n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \cos(kx)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm being asked to prove that, for some coefficients $a_k$,
$$
\cos^n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \cos(kx)
$$

I think I got pretty close,
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^n(x) & = { \left( \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \right) ^n} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} {\left( \frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right)}^k {\left( \frac{e^{-ix}}{2} \right)}^{n-k} \\
& = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} e^{i(2k-n)x} \\
& = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}\cos((2k-n)x) \\
\end{align}
$$

But I can't seem to get any further...

Comment: Why not use $\cos(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b))$ ? Of course it would be better to finish your argument since as you said you seems pretty close but I don't really see how to finish ...

Comment: Did you try expanding the cosine term at the end using the difference angle formula?

Comment: Yes, I got two sums and couldn't combine them at the end.

Comment: Use induction. If you _really_ want to understand how this works, see how $\cos nx$ is an n-th degree polynomial in $\cos x$.

Comment: @galah92 I think you are almost done at that point. The sum contains terms $b_j = \cos(j\,x)$ with $-n \le j \le n\,$. But $\cos$ is an even function, and you can verify that $b_{-j}=b_j\,$, so grouping the symmetric terms will give the form that you are after.

Comment: @dxiv I didn't even think in that direction. Works perfectly, thanks!